# in range() for loop, changing values in a list with indexes

Tags: python

For a part of a Python exam I have coming up, I have to write the output of given code as it would be executed in a Python shell.

I'm having trouble understanding this question:

```
alist = [1] * 10    #[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
for i in range(1, 10):  #from 1 up to and not including 10 - 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
    alist[i] += alist[i-1]
print(alist)
```

My understanding of this question is for each `i in range(1, 10)`, 1 - 9, the index of `i` in `alist` is equal to the index of `i` + the index of `i-1`. My original output was:

```
[1, 2, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17]
```

The actual output is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

To try and understand what was happening, I tried replacing the `[i-1]` with `[i]` and got the output:

```
[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

I have tried various written outputs to attempt to match the correct answer but I can't seem to find the correct method. If anyone could help me to understand what is happening at `alist[i] += alist[i-1]` or if my understanding is mistaken elsewhere I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `alist[1] += alist[0]` sets `alist[1]` to `1 + 1` so `2`. Next, ``alist[2] += alist[1]` sets `alist[2]` to `1 + 2`, so `3`. Etc.

Comment: Why not add `print()` calls **in the loop** so you can see how the list changes as you assign?

Comment: [9 is a very odd prime](https://www.ime.usp.br/~vwsetzer/jokes/n-math-jokes.html)

Comment: @Robᵩ: *9 is an experimental error*.. ugh, and so is 15. Still, a strange sequence, adding 2 each step past the 2nd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your loop starts with a list of `1` values. You then run a loop that adds up the value *at an index* with the value at the *preceding index*.

Either you are missing that the values are 'live', so each time `alist[i]` is referenced, the *current object at that position* is produced, *or* you are misinterpreting `i` as the value being summed and not as merely an index into the list.

I've added some print statements to illustrate what actually happens:

```
>>> alist = [1] * 4   # smaller for demo conciseness
>>> for i in range(1, 4):
...     print(f' --- {i} ---')
...     print(f'before {alist}')
...     print(' ' * (4 + (i * 3)), 'i -^')
...     print(f'alist[i]: {alist[i]}, alist[i-1]: {alist[i-1]}')
...     alist[i] += alist[i-1]
...     print(f'after: {alist}\n')
...
 --- 1 ---
before [1, 1, 1, 1]
        i -^
alist[i]: 1, alist[i-1]: 1
after: [1, 2, 1, 1]

 --- 2 ---
before [1, 2, 1, 1]
           i -^
alist[i]: 1, alist[i-1]: 2
after: [1, 2, 3, 1]

 --- 3 ---
before [1, 2, 3, 1]
              i -^
alist[i]: 1, alist[i-1]: 3
after: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Note how the `alist[i-1]` values reflect the result stored in the preceding iteration; you are not adding `1 + 1`, you are adding `1 + previous result`.

Comment: Thanks for this, I completely understand what is happening now.